# How do I make a shaped fluidSurfaceActor in UDK?

Tags: 3d, udk, level-design

I'm trying to make a fountain for my level in UDK. I've made the base of a fountain by using a `Cylinder` build and now I'm trying to put water in it. I want to use the `fluidSurfaceActor` but I notice that it's square, while my fountain is a cylinder!

Is there a way I can change the shape of the `fluidSurfaceActor` to fit the builder brush shape or is there another way to do this?

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about:

[image: unfinished fountain]